# In R Shiny how do I use an Action Button to change the output in the main panel?

Tags: r, shiny

The below MWE code works as intended, mostly (there are some small bugs that don't matter for the sake of example; these appeared when slimming the code down for ease of presentation). As the user inputs into the side panel on the left, the plot outputs in the main panel reactively (immediately) reflect those inputs. What I want so far.

Note the 2 action buttons at the top of the main panel: "Vector plot" and "Vector values" (id = 'showVectorPlotBtn' and 'showVectorValueBtn', respectively). How would I adjust the code to reflect the following functionality? (a) When the user clicks on "Vector values", the plot is replaced with a data table of those same values - that data table would have the same reactivity as the plot; (b) when the user clicks on "Vector plot" while viewing "Vector values", the plot is restored without resetting values - the last values input are retained in the plot; and (c) when the App is first invoked, the main panel always defaults to the plot as it currently does.

How can this be done? I've been fiddling with this for a while and am stuck.

Here is the MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA
  b <- c(1,b)  
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z                                       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]               
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}     
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y    
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                       
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                       
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

button  <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,)}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 helpText("Select output:"),
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 plotOutput("graph1")),
        tabPanel("Data", value=3, 
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==2"),
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3")),
        tabPanel("Plot", value=4, plotOutput("plot")), 
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods              <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input           <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input         <-  reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        numericInput('begin.bal','',value=100000,step=1000,width = '100%'),
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  renderUI({matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    plot(if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])
         else vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input()))))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is basically the same question that you asked an hour ago? You're more likely to get a good response if you actually make a *minimal* working example; your MWE has a lot of added complexity that isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.  However, your action buttons should work now.  Please adjust to your use case.

```
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 helpText("Select output:"),
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 #plotOutput("graph1")
                 uiOutput("graphrtable")
                 ),
        tabPanel("Data", value=3, 
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==2"),
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3")),
        tabPanel("Plot", value=4, plotOutput("plot")), 
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods              <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input           <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input         <-  reactive(input$vector_input)
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        numericInput('begin.bal','',value=100000,step=1000,width = '100%'),
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  renderUI({matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  # output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
  #   plot(if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])
  #        else vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input()))))
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    #plot(cars) ## replace this with your plot
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    #vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input()))
    datatable(cars) ## replace this with your table
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn, {
    rv$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn, {
    rv$showme <- DTOutput("table1")
  })
    
  output$graphrtable <- renderUI({
    rv$showme
  })
  
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you YBS that works. I post the complete resolved code below.

Answer (score 0):

Following YBS advice, here is the complete resolved MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA
  b <- c(1,b)  
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z                                       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]               
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}     
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y    
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                       
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                       
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

button  <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,)}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}
  
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 helpText("Select output:"),
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values',style="width:90px;font-size:80%"),
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")
        ),
        tabPanel("Data", value=3, 
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==2"),
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3")),
        tabPanel("Plot", value=4, plotOutput("plot")), 
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods              <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input           <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input         <-  reactive(input$vector_input)
  rv                   <-  reactiveValues()
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        numericInput('begin.bal','',value=100000,step=1000,width = '100%'),
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset',style="width:8vw;margin-bottom:10px"),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  renderUI({matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
     plot(if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])
          else vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input()))))
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])
    else vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{rv$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{rv$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})

  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({rv$showme})

}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```